# Show/Hide div using if then statement (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, if-statement

I have this show/hide set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/TwDSx/38/

What I would like to do is have the plus sign go away if the content is showing and vise versa if the content isn't showing hide the minus sign and show the plus.

I read articles on this using images to swap out, but nothing with just using html/css. Also, I would like to keep the javascript out of the html if this is possible, and just call for it externally.

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT :

You can attach an event handler on your click to toggle the display attribute of the `+` or `-` button

```
$('#hide,#show').click(function(){
  $('#hide,#show').toggle();
})
```

Quick demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/TwDSx/39/

Comment: Questions and answers need code provided within the post. Linking to code off-site alone is not suitable.

Comment: dude ... I didn't link to my personal blog or anything.. nor am I promoting jsfiddle..

Comment: I simply said "off-site". The point is that when that fiddle disappears (not under StackOverflow's control), this answer becomes useless.  It's fine to link to jsfiddle for code demonstration, but you need to include the code in your post, too.

Comment: Please try to post your code within the answer itself. There may be times when it's impractical or otherwise needs "treatment", but especially when you don't have Linus Torvald's War and Peace for an answer, put the code in the answer block. It's just lazy not to. `:)`

Comment: What you have in that fiddle, really, is more akin to "War war, what is it good for?!?!" Make your answers self-depicting and **complete** as possible. This is brief and honestly, I have not a clue what is needed, and by whom, what or why.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your Javascript a little and extended it so you can keep it in an external file, you just need to ensure you hide the `#show` div with CSS if you load the page with the content already showing, or vice-versa for the `#hide`.

The Javascript is as follows:

```
$('#show').click(function() {
    ShowClick();
});  

$('#hide').click(function() {
    HideClick();
});

//This Javascript can be external
function ShowClick() {
    $('#content').toggle('slow');
    $('#hide, #show').toggle();
};

function HideClick() {
    $('#content').toggle('fast');
    $('#show, #hide').toggle();
};
```

The Js-Fiddle can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtAeg/

Comment: Is there any way to load all of the javascript externally?

Comment: Definitely, that whole script can be kept in an external file. I've just got in the habit of keeping my jQuery listeners at the bottom of my views lately, something I should probably stop doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to have only one button, `#toggle`, and to change the content of that button like so:

```
$('#toggle').click(function () {
    if (this.innerHTML == '-') {
        $('#content').slideUp('fast');
        this.innerHTML = '+';
    } else {
        $('#content').slideDown('slow');
        this.innerHTML = '-';
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TwDSx/41/)